# Running Moka Papyrus 2.0 BasicActiveObjectExample

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, papyrus

I am trying to run the example from Moka Papyrus website https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus/UserGuide/ModelExecution BasicActiveObjectExample.zip.

But, I got an error like this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.CommonBehaviors.BasicBehaviors.Execution.getBehavior(Execution.java:130)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.Actions.BasicActions.ActionActivation.fire(ActionActivation.java:122)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.Activities.IntermediateActivities.ActivityNodeActivation.receiveOffer(ActivityNodeActivation.java:90)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.Activities.IntermediateActivities.ActivityNodeActivationGroup.run(ActivityNodeActivationGroup.java:107)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.Activities.IntermediateActivities.ActivityNodeActivationGroup.activate(ActivityNodeActivationGroup.java:148)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.Activities.IntermediateActivities.ActivityExecution.execute(ActivityExecution.java:49)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.fuml.Semantics.impl.CommonBehaviors.Communications.ClassifierBehaviorInvocationEventAccepter.accept(ClassifierBehaviorInvocationEventAccepter.java:102)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.async.fuml.Semantics.CommonBehaviors.Communications.AsyncObjectActivation.dispatchNextEvent(AsyncObjectActivation.java:282)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.moka.async.fuml.Semantics.CommonBehaviors.Communications.AsyncObjectActivation.run(AsyncObjectActivation.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found similar problem in http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/diff/?id=b29d8620007e41208e01aee34e0901930dd39755
I thought that it might be different version of Moka Papyrus library.

Environment:
Eclipse Neon 3
Moka Papyrus v.2.0.0

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

found it! the problem is because we do not set the engine. By default, it is not composite engine for fUML. Watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3OIOLvGmzw